# cscope not working properly for out of module development

Tags: linux, vim, linux-kernel, cscope

I have generated cscope database using the following command in the linux source code present in my home folder.

```
$ make cscope
```

I am writing my sample drivers in another folder say ~/LinuxDeviceDrivers

I open my vim file of my sample driver code in ~/LinuxDeviceDrivers and add the cscope connection:

```
:cs add /home/jamal/linux-5.2.8/cscope.out
```

When i now search for a particular tag, for example start_kernel

```
:cs find g start_kernel
```

It throws an error: `File 'init/main.c' not found`

Did i miss any step here?

Comment: You should share the makefile you use to produce `cscope.out`. You may consider using `ctags`/`TagExplorer`.

Comment: The makefile is the standard Linux Makefile

Comment: We need to know how you are calling `cscope` to generate `cscope.out`. Did you call `make cscope` for generating `cscope.out` or to compile `cscope`?. In the first case, we need to know the makefile content to see how you are calling `cscope` to generate `cscope.out`, in the second case give us the command-line for `cscope.out` generation. Anyway, you are probably missing the recurse option   `cscope -R`.

Comment: Linux Kernel Makefile has an option to generate cscope. You can look into the linux kernel sources top level directory. I believe it is doing cscope -bqkR

Comment: You may try to call directly `cscope -bqkR`. Alternatively, `find . -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' > cscope.files` and then `cscope -bqk`.